# Jsf - <h:commandLink /> inside primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to have `<h:commandLink />` inside primefaces `<p:dataTable />` when the table is in `selectionMode="multiple"`. Here is my mock code.

```
<h:form id="myform">
   <p:dataTable id="myTable">
      <f:facet name="header"> 
         <h:commandLink value="Delete"  />

      </f:facet>
      <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
       ....
       ....
   </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

`<h:commandLink />` shows fine inside the `datatable`. The Problem occurs when I click `Delete` link its shows some `NullPointerException`. Here is the error code.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:51)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:40)
    org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:60)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
    org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:232)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.processDecodes(TabView.java:317)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

When I click `delete` after removing the `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />` or set `selectionMode="single"`, the page will reloaded again. I want these stage of action only for my template project.

Where I goes wrong?

Comment: Referring [http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf], the selectionMode is set in the data table instead of the column. Also, the attribute `selection` seems missing - how does your managed bean code look like?

Answer (score 0):

As I know when we set selection to "multiple" an arraylist will used to store the selected rows to use at the backing bean. So when you click on delete, action will be generated and the list is empty as you will not be select any thing, its giving error. Plz post code which you are using so that we could get through this quickly